# Open/close a <div> using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

I have 3 different div and 3 buttons. Each button opens one div and if another div is opened, the first div must be closed first. I could do it with some js. I am not programmer so my skills on js are close to 0.

Each button is using a class: `.button-1`, `.button-2` & `.button-3`.
Each div has different ID: `#div-1`, `#div-2` & `#div-3`.

This is the code I am using (repeated x3 for each button & div):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Hide the div
jQuery('#div-1').hide();
jQuery('.button-1').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#div-1").slideToggle('opened closed');

});
});

jQuery(function($){
$('.button-1').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#div-2').hide();
$('#div-3').hide();

});
});
```

It is working fine. When you open and close the same div the effect is smooth but when you click a different button while another div is open, the transition effect between both divs is not smooth.

Any suggestion?
Here is an example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/n41pcgb3/29).

I would like to ask if it is possible don't allow the user close the `.divs` once one of them has been opened

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your relevant html and css here as well.  Also try to recreate the problem with a code testing resource like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/).

Comment: @ChrisL thanks for the reply but I cannot recreate the code. It shows me an error saying: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: You can't post your html and css here?

Comment: Is that link your page or is that how you want it to work?

Comment: Know that a fiddle-like interface is available here on stackoverflow too. At the editor, click the `<>` toolbar icon.

Comment: @ChrisL That page is mine. I want to show you the effect I want to correct. Once one div is open and change to another div, the effect is not smooth, it is made so fast. 

¿Is it possible to change it?

Also, how can I disable, once one div is open, close it? Once the user open one div don't allow him to close them.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/n41pcgb3/29) with a slimmed down version of your code to play with.  You shouldn't link your website in your question.

Comment: It seems like you are looking to swap divs smoothly.  you can use `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`, and `fadeToggle()` instead of `hide()`. then position them absolutely.  Why don't you want the user to be able to close them once open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap the divs smoothly I would use `fade` method.  I would then position them absolutely inside a wrapper so they fade in and out in the same spot without pushing each other down the page.  You can also simplify your jquery quite a bit. 
 Here is an example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/n41pcgb3/65).  If you don't want the div to disappear if the user clicks on the same button for the div that is open, then change all 3 `fadeToggle()` to `fadeIn()`.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide the divs
  $('#div-alex').hide();
  $('#div-exel').hide();
  $('#div-py').hide();
  // Swap the divs
  $('.boton-alex').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#div-alex").fadeToggle();
    $('#div-exel').fadeOut();
    $('#div-py').fadeOut();
  });
  $('.boton-exel').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#div-exel").fadeToggle();
    $('#div-alex').fadeOut();
    $('#div-py').fadeOut();
  });
  $('.boton-py').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#div-py").fadeToggle();
    $('#div-exel').fadeOut();
    $('#div-alex').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="" class="boton-alex">
      ¡Quiero un fiestón!
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="" class="boton-exel">
      Me gusta la fiesta
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="" class="boton-py">
      Tengo poco presupuesto
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div-alex" class="swap">
    <div class="central alex">
      <h2>Alex Muñoz</h2>
      <h3>«Para nosotros la fiesta es uno de los puntos vitales y más importantes, tenemos un buen presupuesto reservado para ello.»</h3>
      <p>Alex Muñoz, como fundador de Exel Eventos, cuenta con una dilatada experiencia en bodas. Además, es técnico de sonido e iluminación, trata cada boda como una obra de arte única e irrepetible. ¡Está deseando conocerte!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div-exel" class="swap">
    <div class="central exel">
      <h2>Exel DJs</h2>
      <h3>«Le doy mucha <span style="text-decoration: underline;">importancia a la fiesta de mi boda</span><br>
        <span style="text-decoration: underline;">y tengo</span> presupuesto reservado para esta parte de la boda.»</h3>
      <p>Exel Djs es tu mejor opción: DJs animadores que saldrán a la pista si la fiesta sufre uno o varios bajones, y lo más importante… contarás con DJs experimentados y podrás conocerles desde el mismo momento de la contratación, aunque quede más de un año para tu boda. Además, podrás elegir entre distintos paquetes de iluminación para la fiesta.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div-py" class="swap">
    <div class="central ys">
      <h2>Play Yourself</h2>
      <h3>«Tengo muy poco presupuesto y no me importa contar con un buen DJ, le daré una Playlist o incluso me vale con el equipo alquilado.»</h3>
      <p>Play Yourself es tu mejor solución, puedes alquilarlo sin DJ o contar con un DJ tradicional NO Animador.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.swap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.swap>div {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. It is working perfectly. I needed to make some changes. I don't know what they mean due my null knowledge in JS, but the code is working.

I had to add `jQuery(function($)` in all the blocks and close propperly the parentheses.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  you shouldn't need to add that to each block since all of the click functions are already within the `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: I don't know why, but I needed to add that tags, otherwise it didn't work. Maybe is because I am using Wordpress.

Sometimes, the hidden `divs` appear for a few milliseconds before being hidden.

Can it be fixed?

Can see it working here: [link](http://exel.talcualideas.com/presupuesto-3/)

Comment: I believe it is because the DOM must be loaded before the script runs and it is the script that hides the divs.  I don't think you can run the script earlier than `(document).ready`.  perhaps toggle opacity so the DOM can load with with the divs set to `opacity:0`

Comment: You can achieve the `opacity` method with either [animate](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/n41pcgb3/98) or with [fadeTo](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/n41pcgb3/103)

Comment: Great, at the moment is working and I haven't seen that fast flashes of the content. I changed a little bit the code you wrote because wasn't working on WP propperly. I had to make a mix.

· Hiding the `divs` at the begining was necessary.
· Hiding the `divs`while changing is necessary as too.

If not, they have `opacity:0` but they keep on the page using a lot of blank space. 

Can you see the modifications [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wzbpr7no/)

Thank you very much Chris!!

Comment: If you are starting with `opacity:0` in the css, you don't need the 4 `hide()` statements in the beginning.  All that is doing is hiding already invisible divs.  there is a lot of white space because you have also added `#bloque-contacto` to the function.  That div originally was always visible.  You can remove `position:absolute` and let the swapping divs push the content down when they appear but then you would need to toggle `display:none` or something similar that won't allow a smooth transition.  If you can do without a smooth transition, you can get rid of all that white space.

Comment: pssss...by the way, you can also up-vote my answer besides accepting it :-)

Comment: Sure! I will upvote you but I am under 15 reputation.. First time asking in this platform.

At the same time the `div` opens, is it possible to make a scroll to an anchor point? I tried to link the button but then the js action doesn't work.

Comment: Make a new question and I can upvote the question to give you a bit more rep.  Leave me a comment here with a link to it.

Comment: New question open [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293133/scroll-to-anchor-point-using-js). I will vote you if I achieve reputation enough ;)