# Scroll to anchor point using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I use [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/wzbpr7no/) to open and switch between different `divs`. I would need use it to make scroll to an anchor point (it is inside the open `div`).

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I expanded my answer with an implementation of the `scrollIntoView()` method using your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll to a particular number of pixels: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/n41pcgb3/109)

```
var body = document.body; // Safari
var html = document.documentElement; // Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera places the overflow at the <html> level, unless else is specified. Therefore, we use the documentElement property for these browsers
body.scrollTop += 100;
html.scrollTop += 100;
```

Scroll to an element: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/n41pcgb3/119)

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("scroll");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

Using your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/wbqst8f3/2/) as the example, declare the variable outside of the functions so it is global.

Comment: Cool, it works. I am using your second option [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgalilea/g2pncrzd/11/). Can see it working in the website [here](http://exel.talcualideas.com/presupuesto-3/).

- Is it possible to make a smooth scroll? For the normal links I use a class that makes it, but I can't do it in this way.

- Is it possible to add a delay in time to the scroll?

Thanks Chris!

Comment: Did you notice in the css of my jsFiddle:  `html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}`